# How can I have created data (id) returned for a GraphQL mutation?

Tags: graphql

I have a mutation which is successfully creating an entry, but the data returned for the mutation does not include the fields I specify, such as `id`.

```
mutation saveWindowCleaningRequest($title: String!, $frontendInput: String!) {
  save_pdWindowCleaningRequests_pdWindowCleaningRequests_Entry(title: $title, siteId: 2, frontendInput: $frontendInput, authorId: 1) {
    id
    title
    ... on pdWindowCleaningRequests_pdWindowCleaningRequests_Entry {
      frontendInput
    }
  }
}
```

Data returned:

```
{
  "data": {
    "save_pdWindowCleaningRequests_pdWindowCleaningRequests_Entry": null
  }
}
```

Mutation result screenshot:

[image]

Subsequent entry query result screenshot, showing entry was created:

[image]

I'm running Craft 3.5.15.1 with PostgreSQL 12.4 in Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this or logged a bug ticket on their GitHub? Currently running into the same issue. If you don't specify the siteId or use 1 it will return the fields. So must be a bug with the implementation.

Comment: For your reference, we have created a ticket on their GitHub: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/7468

Comment: It will be fixed in the next Craft 3.6 release (unsure when or which version that will be though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by yvanavermaet in the comments on the question, this is an issue with Craft. It's been fixed in 3.6.5.

Thanks!